# Issues installing MariaDB (5.5.34) on Debian 7 (Wheezy)

Tags: linux, installation, debian, apt-get, mariadb

When attempting to install MariaDB (5.5.34) on Debian 7 (Wheezy) apt-get outputs the following:

```
Setting up mariadb-server-5.5 (5.5.34+maria-1~wheezy) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
140122 21:43:25 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
140122 21:43:25 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[FAIL] Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

It can't seem to startup the mysqld server.

Does anyone know how to debug and/or solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

more messages should be in the error log

default location is /var/log/mysql/error.log but it depends on the setup.

You also have mariadb so it can be /var/log/mariadb/error.log or similar.

Comment: The folder `/var/log/mysql/` contain files that end with numbers `mariadb-bin.000001-000005` and a file called `mariadb-bin.index`.
The index file contains the paths to the 000... files.

Comment: that is very strange, the files you mentioned should be located in a datadir  - normally /var/lib/mysql ( or mariadb). As it is a debian package can you please run `dpkg -L mariadb-server-5.5`  and paste it here.if it doesn't work run `dpkg -l | grep mariadb` to locate the exact name of the package and run `dkpg -L pkgname`

Comment: This is the output http://pastebin.com/NefVGEvN